# Trying to open a UIWebView link with Safari

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiwebview, uiwebviewdelegate

Hi, I have a slight issue. I have tried all types of solutions I could find, minus the outdated codes, on this topic of getting a `UIWebView` link to pop open **Safari** and load it there.

So far I can get the specific size to load in simulator, but every time I click it, it loads right there. I have to be missing a major step or I have the `AppDelegate .h .m` and `ViewController .h .m` completely messed up.

I was big into coding for devices up to 3rd Gen iPod/iPhones. I know that Xcode likes to update a lot and I have the 5.0.2 version. I am basically a No0b again, since I have been out of the game for some time.

Please let me know if you have any tips. Besides to give it up. lol. I know it can be done. Here is what I have...

```
#import "WIAppDelegate.h"

@implementation WIAppDelegate

- (BOOL)webview:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
   navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
    // This practically disables web navigation from the webView.
    if (navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[request URL]];
        return FALSE;
    }
    return TRUE;
}


#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface WIViewController : UIViewController
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *webview;

@end
```

---

```
#import "WIViewController.h"

@interface WIViewController ()

@end

@implementation WIViewController


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSString *fullURL = @"http://THESITE.com";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:fullURL];
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [_webview loadRequest:requestObj];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement the `webview:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:` method on the class that acts as the `UIWebViewDelegate`

This should most likely live in your `WIViewController` class

```
@implementation WIViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];

  NSString *fullURL = @"http://THESITE.com";
  NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:fullURL];
  NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
  [_webview loadRequest:requestObj];
  _webview.delegate = self;
}

- (BOOL)webview:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
  if (UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked == navigationType) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[request URL]];
    return NO;
  }
  return YES;
}

@end
```

You will also need to ensure that you actually set this class as the `UIWebViewDelegate` I've down this as the last line of the `viewDidLoad` but you could hook this up in the xib if you prefer